# Webpack not loading scss file

Tags: webpack

I have upgraded my project to webpack 3.  Now my scss file is not getting loaded. Earlier it did load, when I used webpack 1.  But now I am following the documentation and tried many different things. But still not able to load the SCSS file. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong or how to load the scss file. The style.scss is directly under /src.

following is my webpack config and package.json.

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const path = require('path');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, './src');
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/js'),
        filename: 'my-first-webpack.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
                }, {
                    loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
                }, {
                    loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
                }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'

                }

            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|webp)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                },
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

- Package.JSON

  `{
    "name": "basavasamiti",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
      "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
      "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
      "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
      "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
      "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
      "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
      "path": "^0.12.7",
      "react": "^15.6.1",
      "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.0",
      "react-bootstrap-carousel": "^1.2.0",
      "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
      "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.24.2",
      "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
      "react-scripts": "1.0.11",
      "react-svg-loader": "^1.1.1",
      "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
      "svg-loader": "0.0.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "start": "react-scripts start",
      "build": "react-scripts build",
      "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
      "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
      "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
      "webpack": "^3.6.0"
    }
  }`

After making changes to Webpack config Now it looks like this, but I get an error extract-text-webpack-plugin loader is used without corresponding plugin. But I have it installed already. My package.json shows an entry for this plugin. Not sure why this error.

`

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const CopyAssets = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const WriteFiles = require('write-file-webpack-plugin');

var isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'; // true or false

var prod = '../index.js';
var dev = 'index.js';
var outputFile = isProd ? prod : dev;

module.exports = {

    entry: {
        app: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/') + '/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/'),
        filename: 'js/index.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    //resolve-url-loader may be chained before sass-loader if necessary
                    use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
                use: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(pug|html)$/,
                use: ['raw-loader', 'pug-html-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                use: 'file-loader'
            }

        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        compress: true,
        port: 8001,
        stats: 'errors-only',
        open: true,
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        disableHostCheck: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new WriteFiles(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
            {
                filename: outputFile,
                template: 'src/index.js',
                inject: true
            }
        ),
        new CopyAssets([
            {
                from: 'src/images',
                to: 'img'
            }
        ]),

        new ExtractTextPlugin(
            {
                filename: '[name]-[chunkhash].css',
                disable: false,
                allChunks: true
            }
        )
    ]

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
}
```

I'm also working on a Webpack 3 project currently. Maybe you'll have a look at my [webpack.config.js](https://github.com/digitaldomainwebsolutions/Webpack-Starter-Project/blob/master/webpack.config.js). It's working well with Sass.

Comment: Ralph, I got the following error when I used your webpack config and modified it to suit my code. 


`
ERROR in ./src/style.scss
    Module build failed: Error: "extract-text-webpack-plugin" loader is used without the corresponding plugin, refer to https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin for the usage example
        at Object.pitch (/Users/kavitha/personal/basavasamiti/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/loader.js:53:11)
     @ ./src/myNavInstance.js 8:0-22
     @ ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.js
`

Comment: I could not copy new webpack config on the comments section, not sure what is the best way to do it, but I have updated my original question, after trying from the suggestion you gave.  Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: `{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
}`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when upgrading you need to make sure you upgrade ALL the loaders too. We ended up with this which sounds similar to your situation. I had trouble finding the answer too.

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader']
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader', 'url-loader', 'sass-loader']
        })
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

We found this link very helpful:

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin